# R barplot - how to add y axis '%' suffix?

Tags: r, bar-chart, yaxis

```
pdf("whatever.pdf", height=4,width=8)
B <- c(0,0.585,0.043,0.006,0.012,0.244,0.004,0.008,0.119,0.012,0.095)
barplot(B, names.arg = c("ce","de","en","es","fr","it","ja","nl","ru","sv","All"), las=1, ylim=c(0, 0.6))
dev.off()
```

The y-axis is in percentages, how to I get the y-axis labels to use a '%' suffix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `axis` argument after settting the `yaxt` to 'n' in `barplot`

```
par(las = 1)
barplot(B, names.arg = c("ce","de","en","es","fr","it","ja","nl","ru","sv","All"),
             las=1, ylim=c(0, 0.6), yaxt="n")
axis(2, at = seq(0, 0.6, by = 0.1), labels = paste0(seq(0, 0.6, by = 0.1), "%"))
```

Or we can specify `las` in the `axis` instead of the `par(las = 1)` i.e

```
axis(2, at = seq(0, 0.6, by = 0.1), labels = paste0(seq(0, 0.6, by = 0.1), "%"), las = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the Y-axis labels are now incorrectly orientated vertically. I used `las=1` before to avoid this problem but your fix seems to break that.  (Please excuse my lack of R smarts!).

Comment: @mwra  It can be corrected by specifying it in the `par`

Comment: @mwra I added the `par(las = 1)`

Comment: Ok, so this graph renders in R but no longer exports:

Comment: pdf("whatever.pdf", height=4,width=8)
par(las = 1)
barplot(B, names.arg = c("ce","de","en","es","fr","it","ja","nl","ru","sv","All"), las=1, ylim=c(0, 0.6), yaxt="n", col="blue")
axis(2, at = seq(0, 0.6, by = 0.1), labels = paste0(seq(0, 0.6, by = 0.1), "%"))
dev.off()

Comment: @mwra  I am able to get the `pdf` using your `pdf` command.  Not sure what you meant.

Comment: It seems the command order matters. After some tinkering, putting the `par()` call _after_ the `barplot()` call it worked - the orignal order gave a 'null device error'. Unguessable stuff. Never mind. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Following @Akrun's answer, below is the answer using `ggplot2`

```
B <-  c(0, 0.585,0.043,0.006,0.012,0.244,0.004,0.008,0.119,0.012,0.095)
A <-  c("ce","de","en","es","fr","it","ja","nl","ru","sv","All")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(A, B))

df$B<-as.numeric(as.character(df$B))

ggplot(df, aes(x = A, y = B))+
  geom_bar(stat= "identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 0.6, by = 0.1), 
                     labels = paste(seq(0, 0.6, by = 0.1), "%"))+
  labs(x = "", y = " ")
```

[image]